# Regular Expression for checking a tag and getting a specific portion of the strings

Tags: python, regex

I am facing a problem with regular expression. I am checking strings like tag:
`<a href="/abc/def/ghk/">test_test</a>`. I want to capture only the `/abc/def/ghk` portion using a regular expression.

I am using python and have tried with different expressions.

Comment: That's not a URL.  That's a tag which contains a URL.  Do you want to parse the HTML that contains the tag? Or do you want to parse the URL that's the value of the href attribute of the tag?

Comment: Also, what expressions have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

I'd use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), as it's made for doing things like this:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<a href="/abc/def/ghk/">test_test</a>')
>>> print soup.findAll('a', {'href': True})[0]['href']
/abc/def/ghk/
```

Comment: Not all `a` elements have `href` attribute; to extract the first `a` element with `href` attribute you could use: `soup.find('a', href=True)`

Comment: Question was - regular expression.

Comment: @Anatolij, I'm providing an alternate solution, which is more versatile than regex.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian, thanks for the info. I've never seriously used BeautifulSoup, so thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Anatolij: *Every time you attempt to parse HTML with regular expressions, the unholy child weeps the blood of virgins, and Russian hackers pwn your webapp.* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 http://stackoverflow.com/q/701166

Comment: @Blender: `BeautifulSoup()` doesn't accept `href` keyword. You could use `soup('a', href=True)[0]['href']` or `soup.find('a', href=True)['href']`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Not sure what my logic was when I wrote this. I think the new code should work.

Answer (score 1):

Is this sufficient?

```
>>> re.search('<a\s+href="(\S+?)\/"', tags).group(1)
'/abc/def/ghk'
>>>
```

Comment: Now add a `class` attribute ;)

Comment: @Blender, I'm fine with doing either way... but honestly, I prefer `lxml` instead of BS for this task.

Comment: I've never heard of it, but it seems pretty cool. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @Mike Pennington: You don't need soupparser. There is `lxml.html` module http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757627/regular-expression-for-checking-a-tag-and-getting-a-specific-portion-of-the-strin/5759405#5759405

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian, what happens if you use `lxml.html` with bad html?

Comment: @Mike Pennington: From the link you provided: *"It is not uncommon that lxml/libxml2 parses and fixes broken HTML better, but BeautifulSoup has superiour support for encoding detection. It very much depends on the input which parser works better."*

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian, From the link you 'read', "To prevent users from having to choose their parser library in advance, lxml can interface to the parsing capabilities of BeautifulSoup through the lxml.html.soupparser module."

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`lxml` to work with links](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#working-with-links):

```
from lxml import html

for _, attr, link, _ in html.iterlinks('<a href="/abc/def/ghk/">test_test</a>'):
    if attr == 'href':
       print link
```

#### Output

```
/abc/def/ghk/
```